# Omnifaces cache in JSF

Tags: jsf, caching, primefaces, omnifaces

I want create simple cache in my JSF project. I view a few method of cache in web app (Guava, Redis etc.) and I choose Omnifaces cache. I found example [here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/11/programmatically-caching-primefaces-charts-via-omnifaces-cache-component.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20JavaCodeGeeks%20%28Java%20Code%20Geeks%29), but in this example Omnifaces is used for chart with tag in XHTML. In my project I created charts dynamically in Java code so maybe someone know how use it in my case. I dont't have `<p:chart>`tag in my project. Maybe is something better for JSF cache than Omnifaces.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/cache

> The  component allows to cache a fragment of rendered markup.

So this is usefull if you want to cache already rendered code which is expensive to rerender.

In your case you need a Java cache. One of the easiest solutions is to use the life cycle model of CDI beans to cache the results. Using `@Inject` inject a reference to your cached results. You may want to choose different strategies depending on your use-case.